# Wordpress $wpdb Custom query not working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Retrieving data from wpdb and returning as JSON: I am trying to populate my custom table data into a input field here is an [example](http://demo.codeforgeek.com/ajaxbox/). I did everything but the PHP query not retrieving data from table.

Here is My WORDPRESS Version Not Working

```
<?php
 global $wpdb;
 $db_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'sonali_data';
 $key=$_GET['key'];
 $array = array();
 $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM $db_table_name WHERE name LIKE '%{$key}%'");

 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $array[] = $row['name'];
  }
 echo json_encode($array);
 ?>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input#$field_name').typeahead({
             name: '$field_name',
             remote:'search.php?key=%QUERY',
             limit : 10
        });
    });
```

Here is My PHP Version works fine same as [example](http://demo.codeforgeek.com/ajaxbox/)

```
<?php
    $key=$_GET['key'];
    $array = array();
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
    $db=mysql_select_db("search",$con);
    $query=mysql_query("select * from ajax_example where name LIKE '%{$key}%'");
       while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
          $array[] = $row['name'];
        }
        echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using wpdb it is already doing the sorting and putting it into array for you so you don't need mysql_fetch_assoc - also you should use wpdb prepare to sanitize the strings, especially when using $_GET as you are vulnerable to sql injection otherwise - revised code:

```
 global $wpdb;
 $db_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'sonali_data';
$holder = "%s";
 $key=$_GET['key'];
 $array = array();
 $result = $wpdb->get_results ( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $db_table_name WHERE name LIKE '%{$holder}%'",$key),ARRAY_A);

 foreach($result as $res) {
        $array[] = $res['name'];
  }
 echo json_encode($array);
```

The ARRAY_A tells wpdb to sort the data into an associative array, the default is to sort it into an OBJECT in which case you would have had to do `$array[] = $res->name`

One more thing, you should use wp_send_json if you are sending back to a wp_ajax hook: so instead of `echo json_encode($array);` you do `wp_send_json($array);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I am trying it now.

Comment: you can explain me what is difference between echo json_encode($array); you do wp_send_json($array);

Comment: @Liam Bailey one more question above php code is extra query file not included in my wordpress plugin file. so should I add `wp-config.php` to the file to connect with wpdb ?

Comment: @SajidAnwar - wp_send_json keeps everything handled properly, like sometimes you will have your json being send as text and you would have to change a jquery.post to jquery.ajax so you can use the contentType:'json' property etc. This saves all these problems, and also handles the die() etc to stop the output etc.

Comment: @Firefog the global $wpdb should be available without including anything. Where are you running this code?

Comment: @LiamBailey I have added a script in my above question where `remote` the file `search.php` called the query. If it now included in any wordpress function then not found the $wpdb .